# VBA in excel, it should return an array

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a function in excel that would give all the relative prime numbers to a given number. However, when I try it out, it just fills one cell with the first value of the array.

```
Function selectE(phi) As Variant

Dim list(999) As Variant
Dim count As Integer

count = 0

For i = 2 To phi
    If WorksheetFunction.Gcd(phi, i) = 1 Then
        list(count) = i
        count = count + 1
    End If
Next i


selectE = list()

End Function
```

Comment: Exactly how are you entering the formula?

Comment: I don't see the piece where you're filling in the cell. This is a function that is returning an array of numbers. All you need to do is iterate through that returned array and fill in cells (increment the cell's position each time)

Comment: I just wrote the function name in an excel cell to call the function.

Comment: This is an array function (it returns more than one value), so you need to select a number of cells, type your formula, and then press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to apply it to the cells.  If you do it correctly, the formula will show surrounded by {} in the formula bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function selectE(phi) As Integer()
    Dim list() As Integer
    Dim count As Integer

    count = 0

    For i = 2 To phi
        If WorksheetFunction.Gcd(phi, i) = 1 Then
            ReDim Preserve list(count + 1)
            list(count) = i
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next i

    selectE = list()
End Function
```

The above function allowed you to return an array of the primes.

However, I made some tiny edit to it:

1. It **returns an integer array** instead of a variant to make it more explicit (ie. `Function selectE(phi) As Integer()`)
2. I didn't set the initial array size to 999 (ie. `Dim list() As Integer`), I used `Redim Preserve list(count + 1)` to make it increase in size dynamic to the number of primes you have in the array

So now we need a sub to call that function and then fill in the cells with the primes by iterating through the returned array. Note that we are filling in the first column and the for loop increments the row to put the value in (ie. Cells(i + 1, 1) = myarr(i)). Also note that I am just testing it for the number 1234 in `selectE(1234)`, but you can do it for any number.

```
Sub FillInCells()
    Dim myarr() as Integer
    Dim i as Integer
    myarr = selectE(1234)
    For i = 0 to UBound(myarr) - 1
        Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = myarr(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried adding the sub, but still when I go to the excel sheet and try my function it still fills just one cell

Comment: copy both my function and the sub into your vb editor. Then try running it. Let me know if it works. I tested it and it ran correctly.

Comment: awesome :) glad it worked!